# Django 1.5.5 to django 1.7 migrate error

Tags: django

I'm getting the following error trying to migrate for the first time a project using django 1.7.1. How can I debug this?

```
mariano@mariano-System-Product-Name:~/PycharmProjects/grupoconsultor-arg$ python manage.py migrate --settings='xxx.settings_dev'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 337, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(app_configs=app_configs, tags=tags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 59, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
TypeError: unbound method check() must be called with server instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: settings argument are not stringified. Did you try removing the quotes?

Comment: You must do `python manage.py makemigrations appname --settings=xxx.settings_dev`
after that : `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Cherif KAOUA makemigrations is use before migrate.

Answer (score 2):

better late than never ;-)

see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22526,

look for check() method in your server model and change name